# Orhcard CMS 1.10 - Setting Content item level permissions through code

Tags: .net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I am creating a new UI on the Admin page which will handle Content Permissions instead of doing it through the COntentPermissions Module UI.
This UI that I am creating will have User Roles as rows and the Content Items as Columns for which I want to set Content Permissions for. So, I check a checkbox below one of the content items and next to one of the roles and I want the Content Permissions be set for the respective Content item. How can I achieve this using the existing ContentPermissions Module or something else.I'm really lost. Helllllp

Comment: So you're just override the template? Not the functionality?

Comment: @devqon I want to override both, as in , clicking the relevant checkbox on my new template sets the ViewContent Permission for the respective Content Item.